# What is active memory and inactive memory

Tags: linux

What is active memory and inactive memory? I am executing the command `vmstat -a` on a Linux machine and I am getting the following output:

```
vmstat -a
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free  inact active   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0 249900 4801880 2649428 8246152    0    0    42    31    0    0  4  0 95  0  0
```

But I am not getting what exactly active and inactive memory is... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question, really.

Comment: Really? Try to run SOLR on production system with 8GBs and be responsible for production server. Then you'll really need to understand how active/inactive memory behaves and what it may cause (in SOLR case out of memory exceptions). Understanding OS basics is crucial part of software development. You can be master in software patterns, lack of knowledge of particular platform will denominate you to plain junior without any chance for succesfull solution.

Comment: I think OSP wanted to tag @unwind. Myself I'd add that systems programming concepts such as active/inactive memory could be compared to an API. That is an interface provided by kernel, which can be used to do decisions in userspace *(as an example, there's a uswapd user-space daemon which could be interested in such system-wide concepts)*

Answer (score 22):

<s>There are two states of "used" memory, "inactive" and "active".</s>

**Active memory** is memory that is being used by a particular process.
**Inactive memory** <s>is memory that was allocated to a process that is no longer running.</s>  are pages which have not been accessed "recently"

to see the memory use `/proc/meminfo` rather than `vmstat -a`

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

you need not to clear this Inactive memory When system reboots this memory automatically became vanish, <s>still If you have a large amount of inactive memory ,you can use following command.</s>

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && echo "" && free
```

**Edit** 
As per @kubanczyk comment:
you can find more information from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305606/linux-inactive-memory)

Comment: You save my day man. I've been looking for this solution for so many weeks. I tried everything on how to optimize my server and it's the inactive memory that is causing me a headache. Thank you very much for this command on how to release the inactive memory. Now I recover most of the inactive memory.

Comment: what problems can be caused by inactive memory? wouldn't the OS allocate them to processes that need them as needed, effectively making inactive memory as the same as free memory?

Comment: Yes, when there is not enough free memory,OS allocates inactive memory for the processes.For the First time, when we Start Apps OS allocate memory to them. when we close those apps the memory which was allocated to the apps would not be freed, instead marks it as inactive. there after if you reopen the closed apps then OS marks inactive memory as active.This improves speed.In some cases Like when you have 8GB of RAM, In that you have only 200MB of free memory and 3GB of inactive memory Then your system gets unresponsive , freeing unused and inactive memory would work in this case.

Comment: Wrong, wrong and wrong! [Better info here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305606/linux-inactive-memory). This answer is ridden with factual errors: "Inactive memory [belongs] to a process that is no longer running" wrong, "there are two states of used memory" wrong, drop_caches for clearing inactive memory wrong.

Comment: @kubanczyk feel free to edit the answer. Thanks for pointing errors.

Comment: can someone explain why drop-cache is not a good idea? i am using that all the time now.