# Linux: memory usage and releasing swap memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, swap, ram

I have observed the below stats on one of my servers.

1. From the top command, only one process is using 15% of RAM and there are no others
2. There are all 0's under swap-in & swap-out columns of vmstat output

But still I am seeing that Swap and RAM both are fully occupied in "free -m" output

top output

```
Mem:  16413804k total, 16390264k used,    23540k free,    59604k buffers
Swap:  2040244k total,  2040244k used,        0k free,   584688k cached

PID USER        PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+     COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                         
10984 mysql     15   0 3100m 2.4g 5472 S    0 15.5   1129:44    mysqld                                                                                                                                                                          
12773 root      16   0 18440 7916 1064 S    0  0.0   65:46.67   IPremoted                                                                                                                                                                       
3108 ntp        16   0 18984 5720 4652 S    0  0.0   54:35.78   ntpd                                                                                                                                                                            
19694 root      16   0 48996 5708 3656 S    0  0.0   0:00.03    sshd                                                                                                                                                                            
11084 hpsmh     17   0  371m 3892 2532 S    0  0.0   0:00.00    hpsmhd
```

free -m output

```
    total  used    free   shared   buffers   cached
Mem:16029  15983   46     0        52        546
-/+ buffers/cache:      
               15384   644
Swap:1992  1992    0
```

vmstat output

```
 swap usage
 si   so    
 0    0
 0    0
 0    0
 0    0
 0    0
 0    0
 0    0
```

Can some one explain this case ?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Those stats looks like normal for system with high i/o activity. What exactly you want to be explained? And I think this is [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) related question.

Comment: Alex, Mysql is using 15% of RAM and there are no other processes which have significant usage of RAM. Then why am I seeing both the RAM and SWAP completely filled up ?

Comment: @Alex, I have used "Top" with "Shit M" to see the processes in the descending order of their memory usage.

Comment: Look at this question [What is active memory and inactive memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529723/what-is-active-memory-and-inactive-memory). This can help to understand why swap can be full, but not currently in use.

Comment: Alex, Thanks for the link. But I am seeing only 2.7 GB under active memory. and some 440 MB under inactive memory. How about the rest ?? in this case(RAM is 15 GB). I could not see any traces of it wither in top or in vmstat -a.

Comment: In `free -m` output you have huge amount of i/o buffers in RAM. Not shure, but seems like you have (had) high i/o activity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45097/discussion-between-uday-and-alexander-yancharuk)

Comment: Please edit/add to your question the result of `sort /proc/meminfo` and `uname -a` (disguise hostname for security purposes).

Answer (score 3):

First you find which process is utilizing the swap space while using below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get current swap usage for all running processes
# Erik Ljungstrom 27/05/2011
SUM=0
OVERALL=0
for DIR in `find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | egrep "^/proc/[0-9]"` ; do
PID=`echo $DIR | cut -d / -f 3`
PROGNAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm --no-headers`
for SWAP in `grep Swap $DIR/smaps 2>/dev/null| awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
let SUM=$SUM+$SWAP
done
echo "PID=$PID - Swap used: $SUM - ($PROGNAME )"
let OVERALL=$OVERALL+$SUM
SUM=0

done
echo "Overall swap used: $OVERALL"
```

then do the below
swapoff -a
once swap cleared then
swapon -a

Thanks
-Arun

Answer (score 1):

Swap is not a problem here. But something using more than half of RAM is.

Swap is full with totally useless data, so you have 2 GB more of RAM to do the important stuff. Good for you! How I know swap contents are useless? Well, zero in `si`. No process ever wants to read this back into memory.

Now the problem is:

- 16 GB total RAM
- minus 3 GB or so used by all processes (I'm guessing you sorted top output properly)
- minus 644 MB for cache/buffers/free
- leaves over 12 gigabytes used by what? Either kernel or some slab or shared memory or some other anonymous pages. Weird. I would examine `/proc/meminfo` carefully to find out the cause.

Also don't look at inactive memory statistic as suggested in comments. [It's useless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305609/26411).